# Jdbc (mysql) unicode behavior

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8, clojure

I have a Mysql database with two UTF-8 tables. Let's call them Source and Destination.

Using clojure.java.jdbc I successfully retrieve a field from Source, a field which contains the 'ă' symbol. Upon trying to save that string in the Destination, I find a '?' in the place where the 'ă' symbol should have been.

This is the sequence that actually saves the record:

```
(jdbc/update-or-insert-values
 "destination"
 ["lexeme = ?" word]
 record)
```

Does anybody have an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used the example from the [Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/JDBC_Examples#Connection_Examples), one obvious thing missing from there is setting the connection encoding. If you didn't catch
that here is the untested example with encoding:

```clj
(use 'clojure.java.jdbc)

(let [db-host "localhost"
      db-port 3306
      db-name "a_database"]

  (def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ; must be in classpath
           :subprotocol "mysql"
           :subname (str "//" db-host ":" db-port "/" db-name "?characterEncoding=UTF-8")
           ; Any additional keys are passed to the driver
           ; as driver-specific properties.
           :user "a_user"
           :password "secret"}))
```

Comment: Yup, that was it! I really don't think I could've figured it out by myself. So, to sum it up, the problem was that the driver was interpreting the UTF-8 format as some other (default) encoding, then saving that 'nonsense' to the database? Anyway, stackoverflow is great!

Comment: @TudorVintilescu the default encoding being used didn't support the character so it was replaced with `?`.